# Representation of projection of a vector in the basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $n+1$ linearly independent vectors $v,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^m$, where $m>n$. Let $S$ be the subspace spanned by $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Let $v'$ be the projection of $v$ on $S$. I want to find out the components of $v'$ in the basis $C=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$.

Also suppose $A$ is the matrix whose columns are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and $[v]$ is the column vector - both in standard basis representation. Is there a way for me to get the $C$-basis representation of $v'$ in terms of $A$ and $[v]$?